# Do Cloudflare's Page Rules support asterisk (wildcard) in the hostname

Tags: cloudflare

I have setup a subdomain rule like this:

```
Match https://web*.example.com/readme.txt
Forward to https://example.com/subdomain-readme.txt
```

But it seems to be ignored. Is this supposed to work? I know wildcard works on the path, but seems to be a fail on the host.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes they apparently do (though not documented so no real guarantee it will remain possible). I had a caching issue previously, but it seems to work now.